# Join Matrices in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, join, dataset, inner-join, outer-join

I have two matrices like the following ones:

```
'01/01/2010'          1
'02/01/2010'          2
'03/01/2010'          3
'05/01/2010'         11
'06/01/2010'         17

'01/01/2010'          4
'02/01/2010'          5
'04/01/2010'          6
'05/01/2010'          7
```

, and after doing a few tricky things in MATLAB, I want to create the following three matrices:

```
'01/01/2010'          1          4
'02/01/2010'          2          5
'03/01/2010'          3        NaN
'04/01/2010'        NaN          6
'05/01/2010'         11          7
'06/01/2010'         17        NaN


'01/01/2010'          1          4
'02/01/2010'          2          5
'05/01/2010'         11          7
```

Any idea on how to join these tables?
Cheers.

EDIT: Really sorry for my typos, guys. I updated both the question and the input/output data. Please, feel free to provide suggestions.

Comment: How did you get the bottom section? What's the operation? Where do the letters come from?

Comment: I can only see 2 matrices in the question, albeit one of them is presented twice.  Perhaps if OP could explain in detail the transformation from inputs to outputs then either OP or SO could formulate a function.

Comment: You were right. Just updated the question. The problem is similar to the join function in SQL, but I can't find how to do that in MATLAB.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I believe what you are trying to achieve are called **inner join**, and **full outer join** in the database world.

First we start with the two datasets:

```
d1 = {
 '01/01/2010'          1
 '02/01/2010'          2
 '03/01/2010'          3
 '05/01/2010'         11
 '06/01/2010'         17
};
d2 = {
 '01/01/2010'          4
 '02/01/2010'          5
 '04/01/2010'          6
 '05/01/2010'          7
};
```

Here is the code to perform the two types of join:

```
%# get all possible dates, and convert them to indices starting at 1
[keys,~,ind] = unique( [d1(:,1);d2(:,1)] );

%# full outer join
ind1 = ind(1:size(d1,1));
ind2 = ind(size(d1,1)+1:end);

fullOuterJoin = cell(numel(keys),3);
fullOuterJoin(:) = {NaN};           %# fill with NaNs
fullOuterJoin(:,1) = keys;          %# union of dates
fullOuterJoin(ind1,2) = d1(:,2);    %# insert 1st dataset values
fullOuterJoin(ind2,3) = d2(:,2);    %# insert 2nd dataset values

%# inner join
loc1 = ismember(ind1, ind2);
loc2 = ismember(ind2, ind1);

innerJoin = cell(sum(loc1),3);
innerJoin(:,1) = d1(loc1,1);        %# intersection of dates
innerJoin(:,2) = d1(loc1,2);        %# insert 1st dataset values
innerJoin(:,3) = d2(loc2,2);        %# insert 2nd dataset values
```

Alternatively, we could have extracted the inner join from the outer join dataset by simply removing rows with any `NaN` values:

```
idx = all(~isnan(cell2mat(fullOuterJoin(:,2:end))), 2);
innerJoin = fullOuterJoin(idx,:);
```

Either way, the result:

```
>> fullOuterJoin
fullOuterJoin = 
    '01/01/2010'    [  1]    [  4]
    '02/01/2010'    [  2]    [  5]
    '03/01/2010'    [  3]    [NaN]
    '04/01/2010'    [NaN]    [  6]
    '05/01/2010'    [ 11]    [  7]
    '06/01/2010'    [ 17]    [NaN]

>> innerJoin
innerJoin = 
    '01/01/2010'    [ 1]    [4]
    '02/01/2010'    [ 2]    [5]
    '05/01/2010'    [11]    [7]
```

Comment: Amro, Thank you so much for the clean and well-explained solution to my problem! I very much appreciate it. Cheers!

Comment: Amro, may I ask you one more question please? Well, the result data are in the form of a cell, right? Could you please help me convert it to a matrix?

Comment: @eualin: If you want to convert to a matrix, all the elements have to be of the same type, thus you can't mix strings of dates with numbers. The solution would be to convert the dates to serial date numbers (`DATENUM`), then use `CELL2MAT` to get a matrix. Something like: `M = [datenum(innerJoin(:,1),'dd/mm/yyyy') cell2mat(innerJoin(:,2:end))]`

Comment: Let me then change the question a bit. In each loop I get the following two columns of data that are obviously of different type. I need to place one next to other some how and thus to construct the first input of the function you wrote above. How to do that?

hist_date = 
    '2012-01-03'
    '2012-01-04'
    '2012-01-05'
    '2012-01-06'
    '2012-01-09'
 
hist_close =

    35.3400
    35.1400
    35.2100
    35.0200
    35.0700
    35.1200

Comment: @eualin: try: `d = [hist_date(:) num2cell(hist_close(:))]` assuming they are of the same length (in the data you just posted, one is of length 5 the other 6, but I'm assuming this is just a typo). Of course the first is a cell array: `hist_date = {'2012-01-03' '2012-01-04' '2012-01-05' '2012-01-06' '2012-01-09'};`, the second a matrix: `hist_close = [35.3400 35.1400 35.2100 35.0200 35.0700];`

Comment: Alright, it seems that it works now but it stills need a slight modification to deal with bigger widths. In this example here we have a fixed width of two, but in practice I will update the initial table by adding a new column a time.

Comment: @eualin: it should be straightforward. If you are still having problems, please create a new question for that part and explain the issues you are having. It's difficult to give answers here in the comments...

Answer (score 3):

In MATLAB, you cannot have strings as matrix elements. For that you need to use a cell array. This is a solution using cell arrays and `containers.Map`s.

```
FirstCellArray = {
'01/01/2010', 1;
'02/01/2010', 2;
'03/01/2010', 3;
'05/01/2010', 11;
'06/01/2010', 17
};

SecondCellArray = {
'01/01/2010', 4;
'02/01/2010', 5;
'04/01/2010', 6;
'05/01/2010', 7;
};

AllDatesCellArray = union(FirstCellArray(:,1), SecondCellArray(:,1));
```

% Create `containers.Map`s for both cell arrays. `containers.Map`s are hash tables.

```
DateToFirstNumberMap = containers.Map(FirstCellArray(:,1), FirstCellArray(:,2));
DateToSecondNumberMap = containers.Map(SecondCellArray(:,1), SecondCellArray(:,2));

WithNaNsCellArray = AllDatesCellArray;

for Index = 1:size(WithNaNsCellArray, 1)
    Key = AllDatesCellArray{Index, 1};
    try
        NumberOne = cell2mat(values(DateToFirstNumberMap, cellstr(Key)));
    catch
        NumberOne = NaN;
    end
    WithNaNsCellArray{Index, 2} = NumberOne;
    try
        NumberTwo = cell2mat(values(DateToSecondNumberMap, cellstr(Key)));
    catch
        NumberTwo = NaN;
    end
    WithNaNsCellArray{Index, 3} = NumberTwo;
end

WithoutNaNsCellArray = WithNaNsCellArray;
NaNIndicesVector = (isnan([WithNaNsCellArray{:,2}]) | isnan([WithNaNsCellArray{:,3}]));
WithoutNaNsCellArray(NaNIndicesVector == 1, :) = [];
```

Then `WithNaNsCellArray` contains the result with `NaN` rows and `WithoutNaNsCellArray` contains the result without `NaN` rows.

```
WithNaNsCellArray = 
'01/01/2010'    [  1]    [  4]
'02/01/2010'    [  2]    [  5]
'03/01/2010'    [  3]    [NaN]
'04/01/2010'    [NaN]    [  6]
'05/01/2010'    [ 11]    [  7]
'06/01/2010'    [ 17]    [NaN]

WithoutNaNsCellArray = 
'01/01/2010'    [ 1]    [4]
'02/01/2010'    [ 2]    [5]
'05/01/2010'    [11]    [7]
```

Comment: +1 for understanding the question and providing a complete answer.

Comment: Sorry for my mistake, could you please take a look in the updated question?

Comment: @eualin I edited my answer according to the change in question. I also reorganized my code a little bit to make it clearer.

Comment: I have cleaned it up a bit for readability (removed edit warnings). The original question has been stable for a while now so people won't be confused as to what exactly you are answering to.

Answer (score 0):

The statistics toolbox contains a function called JOIN that basically does what you want.

http://www.mathworks.de/de/help/stats/dataset.join.html

Unfortunately, it probably can't handle strings and polytyped matrices. But you might be able to use JOIN to shorten the solutions proposed by the other answers.