# How to pass elements to a different cell array given a specific condition

Tags: arrays, matlab, string-matching, similarity, cell-array

I am working with `Matlab`, and I have two different cell arrays with several elements.

A primary and a secondary one. There is one element that is common in both cells, although the number of rows and order is not equal. What I would like is for X extra elements from the secondary cell to ‘pass’ to the primary one every time a condition is verified. The condition would be if column Y (from primary cell) and Z (from secondary cell) match. For instance:

```
Primary cell array:

ABC 970508 …

FED 970524 …

BAC 970601 …

IGH 970606 …

Secondary cell array

IGH FINANCE BANK1

FED HEALTH PILLS

ABC FINANCE BANK3

What I would like to get in the ‘new’ primary cell array:

ABC 970508 FINANCE BANK3

FED 970524 HEALTH PILLS

BAC 970601 …

IGH 970606 FINANCE BANK1
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Are those `similar-elements` always of three characters?

Comment: No, the elements vary from numbers with 6 digits to words or even sentences!

Answer (score 0):

I believe that what you want to do would be an *inner join* if you were working with databases. Joining cell arrays is discussed more fully in [Join Matrices in MATLAB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10981570/join-matrices-in-matlab), but applying it to your specific case the following code should give you what you want:

```
d1 = {'ABC' 970508
    'FED' 970524
    'BAC' 970601
    'IGH' 970606};

d2 = {'IGH' 'FINANCE' 'BANK1'
    'FED' 'HEALTH' 'PILLS'
    'ABC' 'FINANCE' 'BANK3'};

%// get all possible keys, and convert them to indices starting at 1
[keys,~,ind] = unique( [d1(:,1);d2(:,1)] );

%// inner join
ind1 = ind(1:size(d1,1));
ind2 = ind(size(d1,1)+1:end);

loc1 = ismember(ind1, ind2);
loc2 = ismember(ind2, ind1);

innerJoin = cell(sum(loc1),3);
innerJoin(:,1) = d1(loc1,1);
innerJoin(:,2) = d1(loc1,2);        
innerJoin(:,3) = d2(loc2,2);
innerJoin(:,4) = d2(loc2,3);
```

This gives

```
innerJoin = 

'ABC'    [970508]    'FINANCE'    'BANK1'
'FED'    [970524]    'HEALTH'     'PILLS'
'IGH'    [970606]    'FINANCE'    'BANK3'
```

It also appears that recent versions of MATLAB have a *table* type which has a native *innerjoin* function, so you could use these instead of cell arrays. See [the Mathworks documentation](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/innerjoin.html). However, this isn't in my version of MATLAB, which is 2012a.

Comment: Hey! Your code gives me this error:
Error in cell/unique (line 90)
 [varargout{1:nlhs}] = celluniqueR2012a(varargin{:}); Do you know what it means? Thanks a lot for your help

Comment: I think you are missing the useful information in the error - this is just the line in the function cell/unique where it is erroring. Based on your comment in the other answer, I suspect you are running out of memory - are you trying to run this on huge arrays? My suggestion would be that you look at ways to split the d1 and d2 arrays into a more manageable size and loop over these.

Comment: Now I don't get an error, but the innerJoin variable gives me a cell of 0 rows and 6 columns.

Comment: Name           Size            Bytes  Class    Attributes

  innerJoin      0x6                 0  cell

Answer (score 0):

How would you like a vectorized solution with `bsxfun`?

**Code**

```
%%// a1 and a2 are primary and secondary cell arrays resepectively

a1 ={
'a' 'ABC is correct' '970508'
'bb' 'FED' '970524'
'dwd' 'BAC' '970601'
'hoi' 'IGH' '970606'}

a2 = {
'what' 'gap' 'IGH' 'FINANCE BANK1'
'nope' 'seal' 'FED' 'HEALTH PILLS'
'yes' 'solo' 'ABC is correct' 'FINANCE BANK3'}

X = 1;%// Number of extra columns to append from secondary cell array
Y = 2;%%// Column number from primary cell array to choose from
Z = 3;%%// Column number from secondary cell array to choose from

a1col = char(a1(:,Y))
a2col = char(a2(:,Z))

ad1 = size(a2col,2)-size(a1col,2)

a1col = [a1col repmat(' ',size(a1,1),ad1)]
a2col = [a2col repmat(' ',size(a2,1),-ad1)]

tt1 = a1col-'0'
tt2 = a2col-'0'

tt3 = permute(tt2,[3 2 1])
p1 = bsxfun(@eq,tt1,tt3)
p2 = squeeze(all(p1,2))

[v1,v2] = max(p2,[],2)

%// out is the desired output
out = cell(size(a1,1),size(a1,2)+X)
out(:,1:size(a1,2)) = a1
out(v1,:) = horzcat(a1(v1,:),a2(v2(v1),Z+1:Z+X))
```

**Output**

```
a1 = 
    'a'      'ABC is correct'    '970508'
    'bb'     'FED'               '970524'
    'dwd'    'BAC'               '970601'
    'hoi'    'IGH'               '970606'

a2 = 
    'what'    'gap'     'IGH'               'FINANCE BANK1'
    'nope'    'seal'    'FED'               'HEALTH PILLS' 
    'yes'     'solo'    'ABC is correct'    'FINANCE BANK3'


out = 
    'a'      'ABC is correct'    '970508'    'FINANCE BANK3'
    'bb'     'FED'               '970524'    'HEALTH PILLS' 
    'dwd'    'BAC'               '970601'                 []
    'hoi'    'IGH'               '970606'    'FINANCE BANK1'
```

Comment: Hello! I tried your solution but the problem is that it says i'm 'out of memory' so I cannot see if it is giving me the output I want. I'll try to find a solution and I'll let you know if it works. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @user3557054 What are the dimensions of your input cell arrays? `whos` and `size` info on them?

Comment: whos AM1:
  Name AM1 Size 2615054x3 Bytes 62761296 Class double Attributes
whos MA1:
Name MA1 Size 558585x5 Bytes 363213640  Class cell Attributes

Comment: @user3557054 That's huge! Your best bet would be using some for-loop approach.