# How to rearrange cell contents into a single matrix in Matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix, indexing, cell-array

Let's say I have a cell called `data` with three elements. Each cell element contains an (n x 2) matrix. The first column of each cell in `data` is the ID of the data next to it, while the second column is the actual data. Note that the actual `data` I'm working with doesn't consist of `rand` numbers, but are actual specific numbers.

```
data = cell(1,3);

data{1} = [1 rand ;
           2 rand ;
           3 rand ;
           4 rand];

data{2} = [2 rand ;
           3 rand ;
           4 rand ;
           5 rand ;
           6 rand];

data{3} = [2 rand ;
           5 rand ;
           6 rand ;
           7 rand ;
           8 rand ;
           9 rand];
```

I want to rearrange the contents of `data` into a matrix called `rearrange` as shown below. As you can see, ID `1` only exists in `data{1}`, so `rand` is considered to be zero in the third and fourth column of the first row in `rearrange`. As you can see, ID `9` only exists in `data{3}`, so `rand` is considered to be zero in the second and third column of the ninth row in `rearrange`.

```
rearrange = [1 rand 0    0    ; 
             2 rand rand rand ;
             3 rand rand 0    ;
             4 rand rand 0    ;
             5 rand rand rand ;
             6 0    rand rand ;
             7 0    0    0    ;
             8 0    0    rand ;
             9 0    0    rand];
```

In this case the unique IDs are `1:9` but I want to automate the list of unique IDs rather than just saying `1:9`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Join Matrices in MATLAB](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10981570/join-matrices-in-matlab)

Comment: side note, `rearrange` is a builtin matlab function, so shouldn't be used as a variable name if possible

Comment: @Trogdor I think I may be using an older version where `rearrange` doesn't seem to exist (2015a). I'll be careful next time though.

Comment: @Senyokbalgul, You are correct, rearrange is not a function, I was confused

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done using a `for` loop pretty easily:

```
CellData = data; 
for n = 1:length(CellData) %loop through each cell
    indices = CellData{n}(:,1); %extract indices
    values = CellData{n}(:,2); % extract values
    Matrix(indices, n) = values; %assign values to correct location
end
% add the first column in
sMatrix = size(Matrix);
counter = 1:sMatrix(1);
finalMatrix = [counter' Matrix];
```

Comment: Thank you for the simple solution

Answer (score 1):

you can use for loop:

```
for i = 1: length(data)
    rearrange(data{i}(:,1),i+1) = data{i}(:,2);
end
rearrange(:,1) = 1:size(rearrange,1);
```

Comment: good solution, although I would recommend preallocating your final array

Comment: @rahnema1 Thank you for your help.

Comment: @Trogdor OK, but this requires one more step to compute max of IDs, so the answer may seems that to be more complicated.You may add preallocation to your answer

Comment: @rahnema1, hah, you're right, I missed preallocation in my answer too, you're right, it is not as trivial as I was thinking